# Send MMS using Google's Firebase or Apache Kafka

Tags: firebase, apache-kafka, twilio

Can we able to send MMS using Google's Firebase or Apache Kafka to a mobile number ?
Firebase supports only Push notifications or can we able to send SMS/MMS ?

Thanks

Comment: One possible way is to use a Cloud Function which calls the Twilio API, see https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has no support for delivering arbitrary SMS or MMS messages on your behalf. Neither does Apache Kafka.

You can use a provider such as Twilio (as Renaud commented) and call that from Cloud Functions, or from some other software component.